How do I understand this Hadith on lady singer from Musnad Ahmed?
Salam, I stumbled upon this hadith in Musnad Ahmed (also in Tabarani & Silsilah as-Sahihah) link here. and has been authenticated by ibn Hajar Haythami & Al-Shawkani. I just need help understanding it in the light of the difference of opinion in musical instruments/singing.

عنه أن امرأة جاءت إلى رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم، فقال: “يا عائشة، أتعرفين هذه؟ قالت: لا يا نبي الله، فقال: “هذه قينة بني فلان تُحبين أن تغنيك؟”، قالت: نعم، قال: فأعطاها طبقاً، فغنتها، فقال النبي صلى الله عليه وسلم: “قد نفخ الشيطان في منخريها
“A woman came to the Prophet and he said: “O Aisha, do you know this person?”
Aisha said: “No, O Messenger of God.”
The Prophet said: “This is songstress of such and such tribe, would you like her to sing for you?”
Aisha said: “Yes.”
Then she was given a plate (to beat on) and she began to sing.
The Prophet said: “Satan has blown into her nostrils.”
“Musnad Ahmad”, 3/449,
“Tabarani”, 7/187,
“Silsilah as-Sahihah”, 3282.

1.The questions that I have are about the meaning of the word (طبقاً) and is it a percussion instrument (that is different from the duff), if so how do understand it in the light of bukhari 5590 (ma'azif hadith)?
2.Then about the fact that prophet muhammad (pbuh) is listenig to a lady singer with Aisha (ra), is the prophet allowed to listen to a non-mahram singer?
3.Did this event happen during eid, or a wedding, or was this a normal day in mecca/medina?
4.Final question is what does "satan has blown into her nostrils" mean, does it imply makruh since then aisha did just listen to her sing, i wound't think it would be haram?
Jazakllahir

I found the answer to part 4. here
on page 9 titled "AN ANALYSIS ON MUSIC ENTERTAINMENT FROM THE PERSPECTIVE FOURTH YEAR STUDENTS OF FIQH AND FATWA" by Mohamad Aniq Aiman Alias & Amalina Ahmad Tajudin

"Satan has blown through her two nostrils."
Hadith. Musnad Ahmad. Number 15407)


According to Sheikh Yusuf bin Abdullah al-Judai’ while interpreting this
hadith, stated that the Prophet himself did not prohibit music and singing. The phrase
the devil has blown through her nostrils’ indicates that the music is closer to the bathil
category, in the sense that there is no good (hasanat) to it and that the devil has a part
in it. But this does not mean that it is forbidden, because it needs to be distinguished
between illegal and bathil. If the music was illegal, the Prophet will not allow the
woman to sing and let her wife, Aisyah to hear it.

I just need help with parts 1-3.
